# How to determine speed of swipe on a horizontal scrollview?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making my own horizontal scroll view the app will be some thing like facebook which contain the homepage , friends , notification,etc.

I want to move between pages on swipe: I considered the difference on moving position to be the criteria to determine if I move to the next page or I still in the current page . it worked well but I also found on facebook if the swipe is fast it will move to next page.

So, The question now how to determine if the swipe is fast or not?

Answer (score 0):

Store the start position of the swipe. When the swipe has ended, get the end position and total time elapsed since the touch began. You can then figure out how far over what time the swipe was executed, getting the "velocity" of the swipe.
Some example code:

```
float swipevelocity;
Vector2 touchBeginPos, touchEndPos;
float touchTime;
bool isTouching;

void Update()
{
   if (//..touchstarted)
       TouchBegin();
   else if (//..touchended)
       TouchEnd();
   if (isTouching)
       touchTime += Time.deltaTime;
}

void TouchBegin()
{
   touchBeginPos = touch.position;
   isTouching = true;
   touchTime = 0; //reset touchtime
}

void TouchEnd()
{
   touchEndPos = touch.position;
   isTouching = false; // stop touch timer
   swipevelocity = Vector2.distance(touchBeginPos, touchEndPos) / touchTime;
}
```

You can then set some criteria like minimum distance and minimum velocity needed to change pages.

Comment: thank you for your answer but the main problem is determine the velocity , is there any common method to set minimum velocity also set it with reference to screen size or fixed velocity .

Comment: I'm not familiar with a common method. relative to screen size would probably be the way to go.